# Traverse two linked columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two columns which I need to traverse:

```
  Product Code    Linked Code
6   AAA           BBB
7   BBB           CCC
8   IPET34340     RLITBRSS
9   BBB           DDD
10  BISCRB45      HLITFSHOP
11  GRCWBMCY0     LG1RRPP 1
12  BI  DS110     WH  DS101
13  SSOSBP  0     SSOSCB280
14  SSOSCB280   DRIF00011
```

eg, I want to search using AAA and get BBB,CCC,DDD

I want to get all products which are linked.

Any ideas?

I can redesign the table if I need to.

Mick

Comment: do you want to have the result in 1 or to rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample for get the result in one row:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.`Linked CODE`
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2 ON t2.`Product CODE` = t1.`Linked CODE`
WHERE t1.`Product CODE` = 'BI DS110';
```